# My Angular tsconfig does not detect my Cypress types

Tags: typescript, cypress, typescript-typings

My Angular tsconfig does not detect my Cypress 12.3 types.  I've tried all kinds of things to get this working, short of starting my Cypress project over (which I suspect would work).

My code runs fine but I cannot resolve this situation pictured here in my IDE:

[image]

At the moment, my `cypress/tsconfig.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.spec.json",
  "files": [
    "../cypress/**/*.ts",
    "../cypress.config.ts",
    "../node_modules/cypress"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": false,
    "types": ["cypress", "node", "jasmine-expect", "chai"]
  }
}
```

The above config is trying to prefer jasmine expect type over chai expect, which I REQUIRE.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the solution.  Must be careful about using `files` rather than `include/exclude`:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.spec.json",
  "include": [
    "**/*.ts",
    "../cypress.config.ts",
    "../node_modules/cypress"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "../src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": false,
    "types": ["cypress", "node", "jasmine-expect"]
  }
}
```